# VSC: permanent display of the function usage

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible with VSC to permanently display the usage of functions? In Webstorm (NetBeans) the feature is displayed by default - see screen. I like VSC but this feature is very important for me. Unfortunately I couldn't find an option or extension that allows this in VSC.

[image]

Comment: do a settings search for `lens`, your language extension has to show this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all:

In VSC, you can search for `lens` in the settings and activate the ticks there. In my case it was the setting `javascript.referencesCodeLens`. Now it looks like this in VSC:
[image]